# blog post not accesible on click

Tags: posts, options, archives, blog

im just developing a web page with the gutenbiz theme and im changing a lot of the features through the elementor webpage builder, i have my blog page set as a blog but the post im editing them on the elementor and then im publishing them,the problem now its that i cannot access this post only on elementor and when im clicking on the blog post they are not responsiVE they are not sending me to the actual post.
so in my blog archives the picture and the description of the post appears but then its empty on the click of read more it doesnt go anywhere.
i hope you guys can help me with this issue thank you in advance

Comment: I'd recommend opening a ticket with Elementor - this sounds like a very specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to disable some plugins and tried again it seems to look like a plugin conflict I will say. however, I might be wrong.

Comment: yes i have done that and now its sorted thank you so much :-)